# DNAT web server behind double firewall

Tags: firewall, nat, pfsense, sophos

I have this topology and I want to access my webserver that's located behind the internal firewall
[image]

- sophos WAN : 213.x.x.75
- sophos LAN : 172.16.0.2/24
- Pfsense WAN : 172.16.0.1/24
- pfsense LAN : 192.168.1.0/24
- pfsense DMZ : 10.10.10.0/24
- Webserver : 10.10.10.10/24

I can access the internet from LAN of pfsense : I create static route 0.0.0.0/32 to 172.16.0.1 in sophos

Comment: from which of these networks do you want to hit the webserver?